# How to access a JS variable from separate display_javascript calls in Deepnote?

Tags: javascript, ipython, deepnote, ipyvizzu

This simple code in a single cell works in Jupyter Notebook, but Deepnote seems to render the `display_javascript` calls into separate `iframe`s. Is there any way to get this work in Deepnote?

```
from IPython.display import display_javascript

display_javascript("var a = 10", raw=True)
display_javascript("console.log(a)", raw=True)
```

`Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: a is not defined`

Example:
https://deepnote.com/project/How-to-access-Javascript-variable-from-separate-displayjavascript-call-hvyWPhDWRGahj9NvgJtuGw/%2Fnotebook.ipynb

Background: I'm working on a JS charting library Jupyter integration ([ipyvizzu](https://github.com/vizzuhq/ipyvizzu)), where I would like to access the JS chart object eventually from different cells in the notebook.

Comment: try `a=10` because it might be a scope issue that you're facing with `display_javascript`

Comment: Same result with `a=10` or `window.a=10`.

Comment: `window.a=10` would still refer to the window instance of each individual iframe; if anything, you'd need to go up a level, so that you are working with the window of the document that contains those iframes - `parent.a`

Comment: Good idea, unfortunately, I got the following error then: Blocked a frame with origin "https://deepnoteworkspace.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.